# java-ee websockets modifying HandShakeResponse in Configurator

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, tomcat7, handshake, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm trying to modify `HandShakeResponse` while receiving a connection from client. But the problem is the `HandShakeResponse.getHeaders()` returning empty map.
Here is the implementation for the manual Configurator

```
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response){
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
        System.out.println("Print Here");
        Map<String, List<String>> map = response.getHeaders();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(map.get(HandshakeResponse.SEC_WEBSOCKET_ACCEPT));
        System.out.println("Print there?");
        if (session == null){
            response.getHeaders().put(HandshakeResponse.SEC_WEBSOCKET_ACCEPT, new ArrayList<String>());

        }
        else {
            Integer userId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("userId");
            if (userId == null){
                response.getHeaders().put(HandshakeResponse.SEC_WEBSOCKET_ACCEPT, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            else {
                sec.getUserProperties().put("userId", userId);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting following in my output terminal

```
Print Here
{}
null
Print there?
```

I'm doing everything as per the http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket010.htm#BABJAIGH

Comment: Which implementation are you using ?

Comment: @ArunGupta tomcat7.0.47 org.apache.tomcat.websocket

Comment: I've not played with Tomcat. If you try WildFly then I can help you out.